# Android: Activity history from Notification

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have Activity A B C D.

Lets say application is not running at all,
and new push notification arrived.

When click on notification, it should open activity D.

How to open activity D from notification, so that activity stack was A B C D ?

Comment: Go through http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html, It tells how to stack...